# Copy cell style from all input sheets to output file

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3ciP.png)For example, I have 3 files with 2 cells each: files (a, b, c). I will stack these 3 files to a single output file. The cell styles from input files will be the same for the output file.

I need help regarding the copying of cell styles from all input sheets. Thanks in advance.

NOTES:

1. wb2 = is the output file
2. wb1 = is/are the input file/s

Here is portion of my code:

```
 infileloc = [x for x in os.listdir(path1) if x.endswith(".xlsx")]  
 wb2 = load_workbook(f"{path2}/output.xlsx")
 ws2 = wb2.active
 wb1 = load_workbook(f"{path1}/" + infileloc[0])
 for sheet in wb1.sheetnames:
     ws1 = wb1[sheet]

     for r in ws1.rows:
         for c in r:
             ws2.cell(row=c.row, column=c.column).value = copy(c.value)
             ws2.cell(row=c.row, column=c.column).fill = copy(c.fill)
             ws2.cell(row=c.row, column=c.column).font = copy(c.font)
             ws2.cell(row=c.row, column=c.column).number_format = copy(c.number_format)
             ws2.cell(row=c.row, column=c.column).border = copy(c.border)

 wb2.save(f"{path2}/output.xlsx")
```

Comment: The code looks okay. What are you having a problem with?

Comment: its only copying the first sheet of the input file

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P9to.png -- screenshot of the output file. row 1 to 12 is the first file with 2 sheets. As you see, only row 1 to 6  has a diferent font size. it is the same from the input file. it is supposed to be both sheet 1 and sheet 2

Comment: Not having all the files to hand makes this more difficult but the code as it stands will overwrite cells with the same coordinates. You might want to use `enumerate(ws1.rows, ws2.max_row, ws1.max_row)`

Comment: i think i found the problem. its reading all the sheets but its overwriting the same row and column. it is not continuing to the next lines